# Show value of Bootstrap 4 range input

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, range

I want to have a range input with the value shown somewhere. In this Bootstrap tutorial, the value isn't shown: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/forms/#range-inputs

```html
<div class="container">
  <form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="formControlRange">Example Range input</label>
      <input type="range" class="form-control-range" id="formControlRange">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

I want the minimum of custom modifications and no Javascript if possible.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don’t think it’s possible without Javascript, but try this simple solution:

```html
<div class="container">
  <form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="formControlRange">Example Range input</label>
      <input type="range" class="form-control-range" id="formControlRange" onInput="$('#rangeval').html($(this).val())">
      <span id="rangeval">50<!-- Default value --></span>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to do it with vanilla JS. Preferably use `onChange` as `onInput` will only get called when the user initially sets a value, not when she changes it.

```
<div class="container">
  <form>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="formControlRange">Example Range input</label>
      <input type="range" 
        class="form-control-range" 
        id="formControlRange" 
        onChange="document.getElementById('rangeval').innerText = document.getElementById('formControlRange').value">
      <span id="rangeval">50<!-- Default value --></span>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but as Bootstrap uses jQuery, we might as well use it, no?

Comment: Sure, Bootstrap uses jQuery and you can go with that. I just wanted to provide a minimal way of solving the issue without jQuery.

Answer (score 2):

```js
  let range = $("#range-km");
  let rangeV = $("#rangeV");
  const setValue = () => {
    let newValue = Number(
        ((range.val() - range.attr("min")) * 100) /
          (range.attr("max") - range.attr("min"))
      ),
      newPosition = 10 - newValue * 0.2;
    rangeV.html(`<span>${range.val()}km</span>`);
    rangeV.css("left", `calc(${newValue}% + (${newPosition}px))`);
  };
  setValue();
  range.on("input", setValue);
```

```css
#search-bar {
  width: 70%;
  margin: 50px auto;
}

#search-bar input {
  border: 1px solid #ced4da;
  border: 0;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

#search-bar .input-group {
  border: 1px solid #ced4da;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
}

#search-bar input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  height: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  animate: 0.2s;
  background: #03a9f4;
  border-radius: 25px;
}

#search-bar input[type="range"]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #fff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin-top: -8px;
}

#search-bar input[type="range"]:focus::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background: #03a9f4;
}

#search-bar .range-wrap {
  padding: 4px 6px 0px 6px;
  position: relative;
}

#search-bar .range-value {
  position: absolute;
  top: -50%;
}

#search-bar .range-value span {
  width: 40px;
  height: 24px;
  line-height: 24px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #03a9f4;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0);
  border-radius: 6px;
}

#search-bar .range-value span:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 10px solid #03a9f4;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid transparent;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  margin-top: -1px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="search-bar">
    <form
      id="product-search-bar"
      action=""
      method="POST"
    >
      <div class="input-group">
        <input
          type="text"
          class="form-control"
          id="search-product"
          name="search-product"
          placeholder="Search..."
          required
        />
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <div class="range-wrap">
            <div class="range-value" id="rangeV"></div>
            <input
              id="range-km"
              name="range-km"
              type="range"
              min="0"
              max="50"
              value="0"
              step="5"
            />
          </div>
          <button class="btn btn-info" type="submit">
            Submit
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
```